# Network settings not saving permanently

Tags: ros, network-setup, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I set up my ubuntu laptops to network with each other following the ROS/NetworkSetup tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Network%20Configuration .
Now, I was trying to set the localhost computer to be the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME.
I've tried both of this things:

```
$ > echo export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 >> ~/.bashrc
$ > echo export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost >> ~/.bashrc
```

Also I have tried,

```
$ export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

Both of them allow me to set the configuration for the first time I bringup anything. But after the first run, my settings go back to other ubuntu laptop that I have, which is 10.1.xx.xxx .

Any help is appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186111/network-settings-not-saving-permanently./) by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-07-11**:
I think this needs some clarification. After your first run, when you are sure that the problem is present, can you run cat ~/.bashrc and post the results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should check what is in your .bashrc file, and make sure that you are only setting one master and one host. Also the ROS NetworkSetup tutorial  will give you further information.

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2014-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on 2014-07-11**:
Do you know what directory this .bashrc file is in?
I tryed looking for it but no luck

**Comment by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) on 2014-07-11**:
Its in your home directory, try to enable the view of hidden files (ctrl-h should do this for you) . Other option is to open it from the terminal with a text editor, for example with the command $ vim .bashrc

**Comment by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on 2014-07-11**:
It is still not saving permantly, I have tried all the different ways possible. I am also unsure if I have a source instalation or a deb installation. How can I know?

**Comment by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) on 2014-07-12**:
Sorry i dont know what you are talking about. As i understand it, when you open a new terminal ubuntu run the bashrc script. So if you set in the script the network configuration, it shoud be set every time you open a terminal. Maybe you should modify the etc/network files in ubuntu, you should search some imformation about this before you change something.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do NOT set `ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost`. This is almost surely not correct. ROS_HOSTNAME is the hostname that the ros master uses to connect other (remote) nodes to this machine. If they connect to what they know as localhost, it clearly won't work.

The tutorial you linked to seems to do things correctly.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on 2014-07-11**:
I want to set things to run on the local machine not remotely.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-14**:
Then just don't set those things. The ROS defaults work locally.